# Callback when saving a file

Tags: android

I'm a newbie and I want to use [CameraView](https://github.com/natario1/CameraView) library, the "toFile" function has two parameters. What does "callback" mean here?

```
camera.addCameraListener(new CameraListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(PictureResult result) {
        result.toFile(file, **callback**);
    }
});
camera.takePicture();
```

Answer (score -1):

It will notify you when the file has been written.

Extract from the source code:

```
/**
 * Receives callbacks about a file saving operation.
 */
public interface FileCallback {

    /**
     * Notifies that the data was succesfully written to file.
     * This is run on the UI thread.
     * Returns a null object if an exception was encountered, for example
     * if you don't have permissions to write to file.
     *
     * @param file the written file, or null
     */
    @UiThread
    void onFileReady(@Nullable File file);
}
```